# Rmarkdown : embed html file to ioslides

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, plotly, ioslides

I produce interactive plots with plotly, and save them as html pages. I'm new to ioslides and Rmarkdown, so I searched through the internet, and found no solution. I want to include a plotly graph with .html extension to my slide. So I tried:

````
---
title: "Advanced Physics Project"
author: "mcandar"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Introduction
![my graph](myfile.html)
````

[image]

and it does not work. What I want is a slide with my html graph embedded inside and its interactive features should work properly. Is it possible?

Comment: I might be wrong but plotly might be included only in HTML based R Markdown formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1: Use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp):**

````
---
title: "Advanced Physics Project"
author: "mcandar"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<iframe src="myfile.html"></iframe>
````

**Option 2: includeHTML**

````
```{r}
shiny::includeHTML("myfile.html") 
```
````

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer!. unfornately it did not work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong.. but shiny::includeHTML("myfile.html") does work!

Comment: Thanks! iframe works for me, plotting a network plot using the visNetwork library. I just need to resize the original output as it is way larger than the iframe..